# Why CCProgressTo (100 to some value) does not work correctly?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to move CCProgressTimer smoothy( from 100 to some value).

I coding 100% to 80%, then move 0% to 80%.

Is it correct specification?

Look at this code.

```
// Prepare CCProgressTimer
CCSprite *sp = CCSprite::create("white1x1.png", CCRectMake(0, 0, 940, 40)) ;
sp->setColor(ccc3(255,0,0)) ;    
CCProgressTimer *timer = CCProgressTimer::create(sp) ;
timer->setMidpoint(ccp(0,0)) ;
timer->setPercentage(100) ;
timer->setType(kCCProgressTimerTypeBar) ;
timer->setBarChangeRate(ccp(1.0f,0)) ;
timer->setPosition(ccp(480,320)) ;
this->addChild(timer) ;

// Prepare Action
CCDelayTime *delay = CCDelayTime::create(1.0f) ;
CCProgressTo *to1 = CCProgressTo::create(3.0f, 80) ; // 0 to 80 (Why?)
CCProgressTo *to2 = CCProgressTo::create(3.0f, 60) ; // 80 to 60
CCProgressTo *to3 = CCProgressTo::create(3.0f, 100) ; // 80 to 60
CCProgressTo *to4 = CCProgressTo::create(3.0f, 80) ; // 0 to 80 (Why?)
CCSequence *seq = CCSequence::create(to1,delay,to2,delay,to3,delay,to4,NULL) ;

// fire
timer->runAction(seq) ;
```

Comment: perhaps progresstimer can only progress forward, not backward?

Comment: Why not using progress bar instead of progress to?

Comment: To:LeamCocos2D

thank you response.

80 to 60 can progress backward.

Comment: Reck Hou, thank you response.
What's "progress bar" ? I do google ,but I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CCProgressFromTo` is what you're looking for.

Comment: It worked! thank you.

One more solve case.
CCProgressTo *to0 = CCProgressTo::create(0.0f, 99.99f) ; // like init(100%)
CCProgressTo *to1 = CCProgressTo::create(3.0f, 80) ; // 0 to 80 (Why?)